# Why does this have the higher css precedence?

Tags: css

Why does this:

```
.cssform input[type="text"]{ /*width of text boxes. IE6 does not understand this attribute*/
    width: 180px;
    padding-bottom: 5px
}
```

has the higher precedence than this:

```
.cssform.wide input[type="text"]{ 
    width: 500px;
    padding-bottom: 5px
}
```

First one has 1 class and 1 element: (0,0,1,1)
Second one has 2 classes and 1 element: (0,0,2,1)

But the first style is applied (IE8 and FF). Why is that so?

Comment: Does your HTML element really have both classes? Also note that specificity is counted in triplets, not quadruplets, and attribute selectors are counted in the same way as classes, so (0, 2, 1) and (0, 3, 1) respectively - see http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

Comment: [This JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mPDV/) shows they work fine. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: Can we see the HTML, it's possible you need a space between `.cssform` and `.wide`

Comment: Try exchanging their places in CSS file.

Comment: @Maheep It should not make a difference. Please try it in my jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to CSS specifity rules, second rule should be applied.
However only in case it matches both rules.  Potentially you apply rule
for input element (what is natural for your case), but your css rule looks for
 descendant input element of element with class `wide`. So instead of `.cssform .wide input` use `.cssform input.wide`:

```
.cssform input.wide[type="text"] {
    width: 500px;
    padding-bottom: 5px
}

.cssform input[type="text"] {
    width: 180px;
    padding-bottom: 5px
}
```

And HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
  <form class="cssform">
    <input type="text" />
    <input class="wide" type="text" />
  </form>
</body>
```

General selection rules are as follows:
1. Rules in `<style>` rather from other sources prefered
2. Rule with higher number of ID attributes in the selector preferred
3. Rule with higher number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector preferred
4. Rule with higher number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector preferred

If not clear enough, you can always check with rule specificity using tool such as
[suzyit](http://www.suzyit.com/tools/specificity.php)

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your html.
CSS you provided perfectly matches following html code:

```
 <form class='cssform wide'>
  <input type="text" />
 </form>
```

And `.cssform.wide input[type="text"]` selector has higher priority.
You can check it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3VAFk/)

Comment: @Kyle: no, but @yko’s saying that this is the HTML that would work with the CSS provided (and it does), so the OP must have different, incorrect HTML.

Comment: That's why I provide my own html snippet. OP can easily compare my snippet with existing html - maybe he has just some error or typo.